# sudo: launchctl: command not found

Tags: terminal, applescript, launchd

I am trying to start my music app, both launched and playing, and a few other tasks, at a certain time. I wrote an applescript that runs after my vpn connects, so I know the apple script is good.

I opted to use a lunch agent for this purpose.
When I try to load the plist:

```
sudo lauchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.start.work.plist
```

I get this error:

```
sudo: launchctl: command not found
```

Here is my plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.start.work</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>osascript</string>
            <string>tell application "Spotify" to activate</string>
        </array>
        <array>
            <string>osascript</string>
            <string>tell application "Spotify" play</string>
            <string>end tell</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>00</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>00</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>00</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>00</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>00</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

What am I doing incorrectly?
Forgive my lack of Mac knowledge! I'm a long time Mac user, but I havent used the terminal very much, and completely new to applescript.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Starting Spotify playback at specific points in time? Do you have it working if you call it directly from Terminal?

Comment: Does it works if you do not sudo?

Comment: It came it does not work without sudo, open a terminal and check for launchctl full path with command :  which launchctl   Then use the full path after sudo

Comment: @nohillside I modified the plist. 
`<key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>osascript</string>
            <string>-e "tell application \"Spotify\""</string>
            <string>-e "play"</string>
            <string>-e "end tell"</string>
        </array>`
The command does work if I run it it terminal, unfortunately I still get the above error.
@Pit Xav No it doesn't work without sudo. I tried your suggestion I get a similar error `sudo: /bin/lauchctl: command not found`

Comment: You have a typo: `lauchctl` is missing an `n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I opted to use a lunch agent for this purpose.

Then the **PLIST** *file* belongs in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` **not** `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and you should not be using `sudo`.

Secondly your **PLIST** *file* is not valid as:

```
plutil -lint ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.start.work.plist
```

Returns:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.start.work.plist: : Found non-key inside <dict> at line 16
```

You also have a typo in your *command* in **Terminal**, it's `launchctl` not `lauchctl`.

Additionally, you do not need to use the `osascript` *command* twice. Simply use e.g.

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Spotify" to activate' -e 'delay 3' -e 'tell application "Spotify" to play'
```

Which translates to:

*Example* **XML Property List** *code* snippet:

```xml
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>tell application "Spotify" to activate</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>delay 3</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>tell application "Spotify" to play</string>
    </array>
```

However there are other issues in your **XML Property List** *code*, so here is how I'd write it and this has been tested and returns `OK` from:

```
plutil -lint ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.start.work.plist
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.start.work.plist: OK
```

*Example* **XML Property List** *code*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.start.work</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>tell application "Spotify" to activate</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>delay 3</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>tell application "Spotify" to play</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>18</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>18</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>18</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Notes:**

The *value* of the `delay` *command* may need to be adjusted. The The target *application* needs to be loaded with the **GUI** showing for before issuing the `play` *command*.

If you are going to use **Launch Agents** and **Launch Daemons**, I highly recommend you read the *manual pages* for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`.

You can read the *manual page* for *`command`* in **Terminal** by typing *`man command`*, then press **enter**, or **for easier reading**, just type *`command`* and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**